# Creating Multiple Team Network

Tags: server, network-manager, ethernet, network-bonding

I've a server that have total 4 Ethernet port. I've created first pair of Ethernet (eth0 & eth1) as team interface (team0) . Now here comes the problem, the problem is whenever I create a second pair of Ethernet (eth2 & eth3) as team interface (team1) it doesn't work. The newly created team (team1) can hold only one connection up at a time and other stop's the connection.

Note That both of the team network are trunk from the switch port from different network. ex: (eth0 & eth1 are trunk from network1) & (eth2 & eth3 are trunk from network2)

Answer (score 0):

You may please Post your /etc/network/interfaces with the Code Tags else we cant see the Configuration you use.
It Looks to me that the Switch detects a Loop... sofar maybe telling also the used Switch might also Improve your help